# There is a way to open a binary file with c++, with ofstream, without it being opened in ios::trunc mode?

Tags: c++, ofstream

I write **someThing** to the file, and that's fine, then when I write **otherThing** from the 4th byte on the same file, the file should say "someotherthing" but there are 4 empty bytes and then "otherthing". The file appears to have been opened in trunc mode. Is there a way to edit the binary file without reading the whole file and put it in a string, make the changes on the string and then write the string to the file?

```
string fileName = "fileName.bin", someThing = "something", otherThing = "otherthing";
fstream file;

file.open(fileName, ios::out | ios::binary);
file.write(someThing.c_str(), sizeof(someThing);
file.close();

file.open(fileName, ios::out | ios::binary);
file.seekp((streampos)(4));
file.write(otherThing.c_str(), sizeof(otherThing);
file.close();
```

Comment: `ios::out` implies `ios::trunc`. Use `ios::app` to append instead of truncing. See [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open) for other combinations. But you will soon notice that `sizeof(std::string)` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: This whole topic is called "serialization", just as a keyword for future research.

Comment: sizeof(someThing) is NOT the length of the string.  sizeof(std::string) is probably 24 bytes (two ints and a pointer)

Comment: IMHO, it's more advantageous to write the string's length first, then block write the contents of the string.  So when you read back, you know how much space to allocate for the string before you block read the string.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen ios::app lets you append but doesn't seem to let you seek to a specific spot: https://onlinegdb.com/XwcZP2t7i

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Hmm, you're right. It seems to be the expected behaviour for `ios::app` - it should place the pointer at the end of the file before each write. It seems that the correct solution would to first open in `ios::out` mode (to create the file if it doesn't exist) and each subsequent open in `ios::out | ios::in` mode.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen  You are right.  This works: https://onlinegdb.com/MnsAyn4No